# PyDev Code Completion for Shared Libraries (.so) in Linux

Tags: pydev

How do I get code completion for shared Python libraries (.so) in PyDev?
If it's just a matter of adding it to the python path, then which one and do I add the .so's directory of the full .so path? None of them seem to work although it could be because I am forced to use an old version of PyDev (if so which version introduced the funcionality)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work out of the box... (and this functionality is there for many years already).

Can you post a screenshot of your pydev package explorer showing your project contents expanded up to the .so you're using as well as your editor showing where code completion is not working?